# I try to query a mysql column which has the name "5". This outputs the wrong column which has the name "22"

Tags: php, mysql

I try to query a mysql column which has the name "5". This outputs the wrong column which has the name "22".

This is my php code, `$pid` is the variable I am getting from the android app and is always a number. When I search with `$pid = 5`, instead of getting the column "5" with artist1, it is getting the column "22" with eternal1.

Basically it confuses the Column Name with # in the first print screen. If the # doesn't exist, then it searches correctly; so if I search with 16 I get the column 16. How do I fix this?

```
$pid = $_GET["pid"];

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TableComments WHERE `$pid` IS NOT NULL ");
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nU7e.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfUEK.jpg

Comment: `$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TableComments WHERE pid = 5)`

Comment: Having column names that start with a number is asking for trouble.

Comment: It should be `WHERE `$pid`` (wrapping $pid in backticks). What I'd really want to know, though, is what was in mind of whoever thought out this naming scheme.

Comment: Your code is **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: The problem is, it's not quite trivial making a parameterized query when params are column names. But yes, one should at least `intval` $pid in this particular query.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I started looking into PDO and it actually solved that particular problem, in addition to preventing SQL injections.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design in the SQL dialects I can think of offhand. I know several people who, out of habit, add `order by 0 desc` or `order by 1` to ad hoc queries, the first to pick what typically is the ID column and the second what is often a "Name" column or similar. They're querying based on the ordinal position of the field in the query (or the schema, in the case of *)

In order to get a column *named* 5, you need to use the appropriate SQL quoting mechanism for your dialect and configuration. As an example, Microsoft Sql and Access would typically use `select * from tablecomments where [5]=5`; in Postgres and Oracle you'd use `select * from tablecomments where "5"=5`, and in Mysql, Quoted Identifiers are quoted with a backtick `` select * from tablecomments where `5`=5 ``. In Microsoft SQL you can also make things more like Oracle and Postgres if your session has SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON, in which case you'd use quotes instead of square brackets.

As an aside, but a very important one, you should not take user input and directly embed it in SQL. If someone were to intercept the HTTP transmission between your Android app and your PHP app (trivial with a proxy like Charles or Fiddler), they'd be able to replay the http request with arbitrary SQL injected. As other commenters have noted, please use a parameterized query instead.

Since you're trying to modify the query itself rather than the parameters, you may need to consider whitelisting the allowed field names (or compare the string you're sent against the fields represented in the schema).

Comment: In MySql it's backticks not double quotes. Postgres is double quotes. Can't speak for Oracle

Comment: Corrected. My memory of MySql is hazy, involving lots of whacking my head against the table.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation; **but** the OP's code already seems to contain back-ticks...

Comment: It looks like you're right; it wasn't obvious in the first edit that I was responding to, but I didn't notice the revision by michi. I think I'd have to go and bring up a Mysql instance to figure out what's going on, which I don't currently have handy (postgres and sqlite are all I've got on my box)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I started looking into PDO and it actually solved that particular problem, in addition to preventing SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the column-name into backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM TableComments WHERE `$pid` IS NOT NULL
```

Start using `PDO` instead of old, unsafe and deprecated `mysql_*`

Comment: It's a little confusing due to the meaning of back-ticks in StackOverflow's wikitext dialect, but I think the OP's code already looked like that: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/aafcdae0-a323-400f-ad3e-15a6ba9f1a15/view-source

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I started looking into PDO and it actually solved that particular problem, in addition to preventing SQL injections.